# Why I am getting empty list with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

> [Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}, Item{parent = '0',iD = '0',menu = 'null'}]

I practiced with retrofit a lot of times but this time I got unexpected answer from retrofit. I retrieved list which full with zeros and null parameters.

Can anyone help me?

[my model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnCOF.png)

```
//here is the my RestApi interface
@GET("api.ashx?getMenu=0")
Call<List<Item>> getAllResult();

@GET("api.ashx")
Call<List<Item>> getTinyResult(@Query("getMenu") String parentId);

// here is the my retrofitClient
private RestApi mRestApi;

public RestApiClient(String apiUrl){

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient=builder.build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();


    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(apiUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    mRestApi = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
}

public RestApi getRestApi(){
    return mRestApi;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post sample JSON response that you're receiving from API. If you've error log, please post it here as well.

Comment: have you tried with postman? if the response is correct there

Comment: Yes on the postman everything is fine, I really dont understand. I rewrote code 2 times to be sure there is no wrong but nothing has changed

Comment: posting screenshots of code is generally not a good idea ...

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to post your **Logcat** what it's said? I'm afraid maybe you have connection problem or you assign the field which are not corrected that make you can't retreive the value from *OkHTTP* report?

Answer (score 0):

that model is lacking the required annotations on it's fields, therefore it cannot be mapped.

```
class Item {

    @SerializedName("parent")
    private int parent;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("menu")
    private String menu;

    ...
}
```